# onclick function is not working

Tags: javascript, php

this is my code ,can any one help me . `onclick` function is not calling on click function insert1(); is not calling when i am clicking onclick button.even if i am using the script in head part also it is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$mode="";
$sno="";
$name="";
$gender="";
$age="";

if(isset($_REQUEST["mode"]))
$mode=$_REQUEST["mode"]; 
 else
    $mode="LIST";

if($mode=="save"){
$sno=$_REQUEST['sno'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$gender=$_REQUEST['gender'];
$age=$_REQUEST['age'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","forsight");
$sql="insert into atomica (name,gender,age) values ('$name','$gender','$age')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($mode=="LIST"){
?>
<center>
<pre>
sno    <input type ="text" name=sno id=sno readonly ><br>
name   <input type =text name=name id=name ><br>
gender <input type =text name=gender id=gender ><br>
age    <input type =text name=age id=age><br>

<input type=button onclick="insert1();" value=insert><br>
<input type="button"  onClick="fnsave();" class="button" value="Save">
</center>

<?php
}
?>
<script>
function insert1()
{
alert("t");
var sno=document.getElementById("sno").value;
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
var gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;
var age=document.getElementById("age").value;
window.location="file3.php?sno="+sno+"&name="+name+"&gender="+gender+"age="+age+"&mode="save";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the onclick event triggers for me, you're syntax for that is right. i think your mistake is somewhere inside the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an Error in your Javascript, this is why the method is not working.

```
window.location="file3.php?sno="+sno+"&name="+name+"&gender="+gender+"age="+age+"&mode="save";
```

See the

```
"&mode="save";
```

Should be:

```
"&mode=save";
```

Also @bhavesh found the other error in your vars, this doesn't block JS from working but creates a wrong URL.

Comment: sir can you explain if(isset($_REQUEST["mode"]))
$mode=$_REQUEST["mode"]; 
 else
    $mode="LIST";

Comment: It means if a Mode request has been made  then `$mode` will be the given var. Else it will be the default 'LIST' value.

Answer (score 4):

```
 ("age"+age+)("&mode="save"), Solution("&age"+age+)("&mode=save")  

window.location="file3.php?sno="+sno+"&name="+name+"&gender="+gender+"&age="+age+"&mode=save";
```